# The term 'sqlite3' is not recognized

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-login

So I am trying to make a flask app login and i did this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin
# from flask_wtf import wtforms
# from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
# from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length,ValidationError

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecreatkey'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

and to create a database also did this:
from app import app,db

> > > app.app_context().push()
> > > db.create_all()

then i got this error:
sqlite3 database.db

The term 'sqlite3' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

the i am trying everything but it is not working please someone help me fast!!!

i have tried it in cmd prompt and it just say
sqlite3 database.db
SQLite version 3.45.2 2024-03-12 11:06:23 (UTF-16 console I/O)
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite>

but it should have user database/table created in it.
PLEASE!!

Comment: also i exit() and ctrl-z also not working in python in cmd

Comment: "*The term 'sqlite3' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.*" means you don't have any executable in your `PATH` named `sqlite3`. It's not at all clear how the invocation `sqlite3 database.db` from your shell has anything to do with the code you've provided. If you need the command-line `sqlite3` client, install it.

Comment: i have installed sqlite3 and set up path also, how do you install command-line sqlite3 please tell me that would help

Comment: i am following a tutorial on youtube https://youtu.be/71EU8gnZqZQ?si=bacpU1pz9CI1_8Nh